# Theme and Style in Android

Tags: android

Can any one tell me how to apply theme and style in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at the tutorial? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Basically, add your styles like this.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

and your themes like this

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```